# Где реализуется абстрактный метод read в случае вызова его на экземпляре возвращаемом openStream?

Tags: java

Открываю поток на чтение, читаю первый байт.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class App00 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream src = new URL("http://www.site.net/").openStream();
        System.out.println(src.read());
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь найти, где реализуется метод `read` в классе `URL` (предполагаю, что это будет метод с модификатором `native`), но не нахожу такой реализации.   Где она может быть?

Comment: URL.openStream вызывает openConnection().getInputStream(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream()

Comment: @gil9red я дошел и до public URLConnection openConnection, но хотелось бы понять где же реализуется read.

Comment: @gil9red Как аналогию я представлял реализацию в классе FileInputStream, где read реализован как return read0(), а уже read0 - это нативный метод.